# junit test class visibility outside module

Tags: java, junit, netbeans-8

here is the architecture of my product into netbeans (8.0.2):

```
module 1
---Source Package
------ com.toto.titi.module1.normClass1.java
---Unit Test Package
------ com.toto.titi.module1.TestUtility.java

module 2
---Source Package
------ com.toto.titi.module2.normClass2.java
---Unit Test Package
------ com.toto.titi.module2.NewTestClass.java
```

Here is what I need to do

```
com.toto.titi.module2.NewTestClass.java:
import com.toto.titi.module1.TestUtility; << does not compile cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TestUtility
  location: package com.toto.titi.module1
```

The visibility of test classes outside of module does not allow to find the TestUtility class.
Do you have any clue to resolv that dependency of test classes over modules ?

I'm aware that dependency over module for source classes is OK:

```
com.toto.titi.module2.normClass2.java I can do
import com.toto.titi.module1.normClass1;
```

Comment: If you're using maven, dependency on "test-jar" should solve this.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what `R Kaja Mohideen` said. You need to update maven to ALSO compile the test-jar for module 1. Then include this test jar as a dependency in module 2.

Check out the documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html).